# In binary linear programming, what's the relationship between the dual solution and the lagrangian multipliers?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, binary-variable

In my optimization problem the objective function and all the constraints are linear. The decision variables are binary. [so, it's BLP] Some of the hard constraints are very time-consuming to be solved, therefore I would like to relax them by the lagrangian multipliers (ie, putting them into the objective function in a penalized way). The optimization software I'm using (*lpSolve*) provides the dual solution of the simplex method (it retrieves the values of the dual variables (the reduced costs)). BUT I don't know what's the relationship btw the dual solutions and the relaxed constraints to be put in the objective function.

Comment: Binary Linear programming where all variables are boolean is also called pseudo boolean program. If this is the case for your problem consider trying RoundingSAT which takes this form or transform your problem to the equivalent MaxSAT instance using an off-the-shelf MaxSAT solver. If some variables are non-Integer an SMP solver like Z3 might help too.
Those kind of solver have stronger reasoning capabilities about constraints then linear solvers. Although they maybe worse at optimization as they resolve the SAT problems for different objectives internally.

Comment: I think it is fair to say lpSolve is quite slow. So I would start by trying a faster optimizer. mosek.com is one option. Disclaimer: I am affiliated with mosek.

Comment: Note that MIP models don't have well-defined duals. You may be looking for a technique called Lagrangian Relaxation. Google will find some good references. This is not for the faint of heart, so usually it is a good idea to make sure this is indeed a problem class that is suitable for this approach (and that other, simpler, approaches, such as using stronger MIP solvers, are not available).

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK, I'm using R (and lpsolve through 'pSolveAPI, which is the R wrapper to lpsolve, actually). I read in Wikipedia that the R interface to Mosek (Rmosek) is "outdated". How much outdated, in your opinion?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, here's my problem better detailed for you:  
min zx s.t.
Ax<=b (where A is m1xn, x is n, b is m1).
Bx=d (where B is m2xn, x is n, d is m2).
Both the objective function and all the constraints are linear.
x is binary.
n is around 4000, m1 the same. m2 is 40.
I'd like to relax the second group of constraints by incorporating it into the objective function, that is:
Min zx + lambda*|Bx-d|.
s.t. Ax<=b, x binary.
Is that feasible with lagrangian multipiers? How can I express the OF coefficients? I feel the dual solution might help me, but I don't know how.

Comment: Wikipedia is partly wrong about the Rmosek interface. We keep it up to date. The page states: The up-to-date version is provided by Mosek ApS

Comment: You just follow https://docs.mosek.com/latest/rmosek/index.html and you get the latest and greatest Rmosek.

Comment: @ErlingMosek, thanks a lot. [To be honest: you seem to me to be Erling D. Andersen, the founder of Mosek. You frankly disclaimed that, however]. As the move from lpSolveAPI to Rmosek (or Mosek ApS) is obviously expensive to me (as to many aspects), what's the evidence you can provide when claiming "lpSolve is quite slow, Mosek is faster"?

Comment: I suggested you should consider other optimizers. Another choice is Mosek but you pick. We have free-of-charge trial you are welcome to try out.  Academics can use it free of charge.  Have fun.

Comment: Probably this paper can help you https://www3.diism.unisi.it/~agnetis/rillag.pdf